# How to connect rss feed to task scheduler (WIN 10 HOME)

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, rss

How would I be able to get a task to run in task scheduler when an rss feed is updated? I just want to use the updating of an rss feed as a trigger to get it to start.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Task Scheduler does **not** support using an RSS Feed as a trigger. According to it's [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page):

> You can use the Task Scheduler to execute tasks such as starting an application, sending an email message, or showing a message box. Tasks can be scheduled to execute in response to these events, or triggers.
>
> - When a specific system event occurs.
> - At a specific time.
> - At a specific time on a daily schedule.
> - At a specific time on a weekly schedule.
> - At a specific time on a monthly schedule.
> - At a specific time on a monthly day-of-week schedule.
> - When the computer enters an idle state.
> - When the task is registered.
> - When the system is booted.
> - When a user logs on.
> - When a Terminal Server session changes state.

Such a task should be approached in other ways, e.g.:

- You probably will be able to set up an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) applet to do what you desire. IFTTT supports RSS feeds as triggers, and has a variety of capabilities.
- You could write a script (e.g. a Python script) that implements your own logic.